# How to get data from multiple children in order angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a gridded response (like the ones on scantrons) where I have a parent component A that has multiple children (using ngFor I call B), each representing a column. I want to be able to get the value of each column sent back to A in order so that A can put together the final value entered. I'm not too familiar with passing data to the parent myself and would appreciate some help

gridded-response.html

```
....
<ng-container *ngFor="let d in data;">
   <app-gridded-col [inputs]="d" [delim]="fixed"></app-gridded-col>
</ng-container>
```

data is a nested list of the inputs for each column (i.e 1-9, +,-)

In the gridded-response component, I would like to be able to receive the value per column from each app-gridded-col child in order so that I can put together the answer.

Comment: Can you add some code? I cant understand what you want. If you are using ngFor then it means you have an object to iterate. If you have an object to iterate why cant you just pass it to the parent component A?

Comment: in your ngFor, you can gather the index `*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"`. If a child triggers an event: `(ready)="onColumnReady(i, item)"`. Does it make sense ?